# Generate qt help file from CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, doxygen

I want to create a online help for my program using the [qt help framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthelp-framework.html). My doc files are generated by doxygen, and I want to generate files for qt help generator from it.

My program is built with CMake, and I've added a target for generating documentation:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.21.0)

find_package(Doxygen REQUIRED dot)

set (DOXYGEN_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS "")

if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile @ONLY)
  doxygen_add_docs(
    myprograme-manual
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/en
  )
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

The `configure_file` is needed because in the configuration I use come CMake variables, like the version of my program and so on.

This is the part of the doxyfile where I create the qhp file.

```
GENERATE_QHP           = YES

# If the QHG_LOCATION tag is specified, the QCH_FILE tag can be used to specify
# the file name of the resulting .qch file. The path specified is relative to
# the HTML output folder.
# This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_QHP is set to YES.

QCH_FILE               = @DOC_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@/manual.qch

# The QHP_NAMESPACE tag specifies the namespace to use when generating Qt Help
# Project output. For more information please see Qt Help Project / Namespace
# (see:
# https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qthelpproject.html#namespace).
# The default value is: org.doxygen.Project.
# This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_QHP is set to YES.

QHP_NAMESPACE          = my.program

# The QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER tag specifies the namespace to use when generating Qt
# Help Project output. For more information please see Qt Help Project / Virtual
# Folders (see:
# https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qthelpproject.html#virtual-folders).
# The default value is: doc.
# This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_QHP is set to YES.

QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc

# If the QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME tag is set, it specifies the name of a custom
# filter to add. For more information please see Qt Help Project / Custom
# Filters (see:
# https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qthelpproject.html#custom-filters).
# This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_QHP is set to YES.

QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   =

# The QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS tag specifies the list of the attributes of the
# custom filter to add. For more information please see Qt Help Project / Custom
# Filters (see:
# https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qthelpproject.html#custom-filters).
# This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_QHP is set to YES.

QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  =

# The QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS tag specifies the list of the attributes this
# project's filter section matches. Qt Help Project / Filter Attributes (see:
# https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qthelpproject.html#filter-attributes).
# This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_QHP is set to YES.

QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  =

# The QHG_LOCATION tag can be used to specify the location (absolute path
# including file name) of Qt's qhelpgenerator. If non-empty doxygen will try to
# run qhelpgenerator on the generated .qhp file.
# This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_QHP is set to YES.

QHG_LOCATION           =
```

Problem is that the file is not generated. From the comments I can see that I need to define the `QHG_LOCATION` parameter, that's the full path of `qhelpgenerator`. Since I use CMake the qt path on the computer is not fixed, and I use `find_package` in order to use Qt. How can I define a variable from the `find_package(Qt)` that allows me to define the location of the qhelpgenerator?

Comment: Which version of doxygen ? You wrote "Problem is that the file is not generated.", which file is not generated? Doesn't the find_package for Qt give you a `QT_BIN_DIR` or something with `EXE` in it?

Comment: @albert Nope, `QT_BIN_DIR` is not defined:
`find_package (Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package (Qt5LinguistTools)

message (STATUS "QT BIN DIR IS ${QT_BIN_DIR}")`
tell me that the variable is empty.

Comment: A bit of a hack: can't you use the path in e.g. the Qt5LinguistTools EXECUTABLE variable to construct the name for the help generator? Maybe the people creating the `find_package (Qt5 C` could shine  a light ...